# Speeding up grabbing alphachannel

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, bitmap

I don't know if there is anything that can be done to speed up my code at all, probably not by much if at all, but I thought I would ask here.

I am working on a python script for a program that uses a custom embedded python interpreter so I can only use the default libraries.  External libraries like Pillow and Numpy don't work because they changed the name of the python dll and so the precompiled libraries can't interact with it.

This program doesn't support pasting transparent images from the clipboard outside of its own proprietary format.  So I'm writing a script to cover that feature.  It grabs the CF_DIBv5 format from the clipboard using ctypes and checks to see if it is 32bpp and that an alphamask exists.

Here's the slow part.  I then need to isolate the alpha channel and save it as its own separate image.  I can do this easily enough.  Just grab a Long from the byte string, & the mask to get the alpha channel, and add pack it back to my new bitmap bytestring.  On a small 300x300 image, this takes close to 10 seconds.  Which isn't horrible.  I will gladly live with that.  However, I fear it's going to be horribly slow on larger megapixel images.

I'm not showing the complete code here because it's a horrible ugly mess and most of it is just defining the structures I'm using for my bitmap class and getting ctypes working.  But here are the important parts where I loop over the data.

```
        rowsizemask = calcRowSize(24,bmp.header.bV5Width) #returns bytes per row needed
        rowmaskpadding = b'\x00'*(rowsizemask - bmp.header.bV5Width*3) #creates padding bytes
        
        #loop over image data
        for y in range(bmp.header.bV5Height):
            for x in range(bmp.header.bV5Width):
                offset, color = unpack(offset,">L",buff) #calls struct.unpack in custom function
                color = color[0] & bmp.header.bV5AlphaMask #gets alpha channel
                newbmp.pixels += struct.pack(">3B", color,color,color) #creates 24bpp listing
            newbmp.pixels += rowmaskpadding #pad row to meet BMP specs
```

So what do you think?  Am I missing something obvious?  Or is this about as good as it's going to get with pure python only?

Comment: Okay, so I just realized (silly me) that it's obviously the string creation that's the issue.  I added a print statement to show me how quickly it progresses through the rows, and it goes pretty quick up until row 230.  Then it slows way down.  Obviously because it's copying, adding, and destroying strings constantly.

I just don't know how to deal with that.  I know of no mutable string options that just let me pre-create a string of sufficient size and replace the bytes with my newly packed byte string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after some more digging.  I realized I could use ctypes.create_string_buffer to create a binary string of the perfect size and then use slices to change the values.

There are more tiny optimizations and code cleanups I can do but this has taken it from a script that can easily take several minutes to complete on a 900x900 pixel image, to just a few seconds.

Is this the best option?  No idea, but it works.  And it's faster than I had thought possible.  See the edited code here.  The changes are minor.

```
        rowSizeMask = calcRowSize(24,bmp.header.bV5Width) #returns bytes per row needed
        paddingLength = (rowSizeMask = bmp.header.bV5Width*3)
        rowMaskPadding = b'\x00'*paddingLength #creates padding bytes
        writeOffset = 0

        #create pixel buffer
        #rowsize mask includes padding, multiply by height for total byte count
        newBmp.pixels = ctypes.create_string_buffer(bmp.heaer.bV5Height * rowSizeMask)

        #loop over image data
        for y in range(bmp.header.bV5Height):
            for x in range(bmp.header.bV5Width):
                offset, color = unpack(offset,">L",buff) #calls struct.unpack in custom function
                color = color[0] & bmp.header.bV5AlphaMask #gets alpha channel
                newBmp.pixels[writeOffset:writeOffset+3] = struct.pack(">3B", color,color,color) #creates 24bpp listing
                writeOffset += 3
            newBmp.pixels += rowMaskPadding #pad row to meet BMP specs
            writeOffset += paddingLength
```